# Google Pay - get full shipping address from onPaymentDataChanged callback

Tags: react-redux, google-pay

Is it possible to get the full shipping address from the `onPaymentDataChanged()` callback? To select deliveries and calculate their costs and calculate taxes, I use a third-party API that requires an `address_line_1` field, but on this callback I can get only an object with a short address.

It wouldn't be a problem, but I need to calculate costs and show it to user directly from google pay widget before the pay button is clicked and payment is completed.

Example of object that I get from callback:

```
{
  "shippingAddress": {
      "countryCode": "UA",
      "postalCode": "49000",
      "locality": "Dnipro",
      "administrativeArea": "Дніпропетровська область"
  },
  "callbackTrigger": "SHIPPING_ADDRESS"
}
```

Some links that I used to research:

- https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#IntermediateAddress
- https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#onPaymentDataChanged
- [https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#load:~:text=Was%20this%20helpful%3F-,Tutorial,-bookmark_border](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#load:%7E:text=Was%20this%20helpful%3F-,Tutorial,-bookmark_border)

Answer (score 0):

The complete address is only available after authorized event, in `paymentData`